# Porque JSF não está respeitando as rotas inseridas faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Minhas aplicação não está mais respeitando as rotas inseridas no faces-config.xml, porque?

Segue a exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1384)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findWildCardMatch(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:672)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getViewId(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:483)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:190)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:183)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
... 27 more
```

Meu faces-config.xml

`<navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>cadastroCargos</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/CadastroCargos.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect include-view-params="true"/>
  </navigation-case>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, Grande dá uma olhada na configuração do teu mvc, ele pode estar procurando o prefix e o sufix errados, ou em locais errados.

Comment: Está tudo como estava antes. Eu não mudei nada.....

Comment: Tu configurou o local onde ele vai procurar as views

Comment: Também tem a questão de você ter configurado o bean que vai controlar essas requisições, também tem que lembrar que o navigation case tem que estar dentro de um navigation rule

Comment: O pior que está tudo certo. Estou usando a propriedade `outcome`, pois não posso parar. Valeu.

Comment: Grande teu controller para essa view verifica se os métodos ou anotações estão corretas, o erro pode ser lá também, qualquer coisa se puder disponibilizar o resto do código fica melhor para entender mais sobre como está sendo gerado o erro